# How to get block user in apns plugin of openfire for iOS?

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications, openfire

I want to fetch the block user from apns plugin of openfire of iOS. Because openfire will send the notification if user is already block. But don't to allow to send the push notification.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I can fetch the block user from ApnsDBHandler.java class.

Query

```
private static final String LOAD_BLOCKED_USER = "SELECT list FROM ofPrivacyList WHERE username=?";
```

Method

```
    public boolean getBlockUser(JID fromJID, JID targetJID) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        boolean isBlocked = false;
        String list = null;
        try {
            con = DbConnectionManager.getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(LOAD_BLOCKED_USER);
//            list.repl
           String fullJID =  targetJID.toBareJID();
           String jid = fullJID.split("@")[0];

            pstmt.setString(1, jid);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                list = rs.getString(1);
//                System.out.println("Found Blocked user list: "+list);
                isBlocked =  isBlockedUser(list, fromJID.toBareJID());
            }else{
//                System.out.println("Not Found Blocked user list");
            }
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception Blocked user list");

            Log.error(sqle.getMessage(), sqle);
            list = sqle.getMessage();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Blocked user list");

            Log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally {
            DbConnectionManager.closeConnection(rs, pstmt, con);
        }
        return isBlocked;
    }

    private boolean isBlockedUser(String xmlRecords, String fromJID) throws  Exception {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        boolean flag = false;
        for(int x=0, size= nodes.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
            String blockedJID = nodes.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue();
            String action = nodes.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("action").getNodeValue();
            if (blockedJID.equals(fromJID)){
                 if(action.equals("deny")){
                     flag  =  true;
                 }else{
                     flag =  false;
                 }
                break;
            }
        }

        return flag;

    }
```

I hope this will help to others. :)